# Erlang's timer:apply_after/4 crashes when ran

Tags: erlang

I'm referencing http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#apply_after-4

```
2> c(counter).
{ok,counter}
3> counter:start().
** exception error: undefined function timer:apply_after/4
     in function  counter:start/0 (counter.erl, line 40)

-module(counter).
-compile(export_all).

counter(State) ->
  receive
    {From, {add, Number}} ->
      NewNumber = State+Number,
      From ! {self(), NewNumber},
      counter(NewNumber);
    {From, {resolve}} ->
          From ! {self(), State},
          counter(0);
     terminate ->
       ok
   end.

add(Pid, Number) ->
  timer:apply_after(1000, ?MODULE, fun add/2, [Pid, 10]),
  Pid ! {self(), {add, Number}},
  receive
    {Pid, Msg} -> Msg
  after 3000 ->
    timeout
  end.

resolve(Pid) ->
  Pid ! {self(), {resolve}},
  receive
    {Pid, Msg} -> Msg
  after 3000 ->
    timeout
  end.

handle_info(resolve) ->
  resolve(self()),
  erlang:send_after(3000, self(), resolve).

start() ->
  Pid = spawn(?MODULE, counter, [0]),
  timer:apply_after(1000, ?MODULE, fun add/2, [Pid, 10]),
  Pid.
```

why is the timer module not loading correctly?

Comment: What does `code:which(timer)` return? It should show that the `timer` module is loaded from the `stdlib` application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs explicitly state that Function should be an atom. You're passing a fun instead. Change 'fun add/2' to simply 'add' and make sure add/2 is exported.

Comment: I have tested this code and it works. So I believe there is a trouble in the installation.

Comment: Correction, it doesn't work but does not generate an error.

Comment: Yes, it seems that if the arguments are bogus, it will fail silently.

Comment: I have checked the source code of the timer module, only the time is checked (must be an integer >= 0) but the {M,F,A} is stored unchecked in the ets, waiting for execution, on time it is executed in a `catch spawn(M,F,A)`, so it fails silently.

Comment: This does work, thank you! I had a timer.beam in my current directory which interfered.

Answer (score 0):

The timer module is part of the stdlib, which is started automatically, but the timer module is not needed to start a new VM.

Verify that the file timer.beam is present in the ???/erlX.Y/lib/stdlib-ZZZ\ebin directory.

[edit]
I have tested your code on my laptop, with the only difference that I changed the module name from counter to count (I had already a counter module in my "garbage" directory). It <strike>works fine</strike> doesn't work fine but does not create error:

```
1> c(count).
{ok,count}
2> count:start().
<0.40.0>
3> count:add(pid(0,40,0),3).
3
4> count:add(pid(0,40,0),5).
8
```

Replacing the code `fun add/2` by `add` makes the counter count, but each time `add` is called, a new timer is launched and the counter accelerates. Is it on purpose?

Another remark, when you use the terminate message, the counter loop is stopped, but the timer continue to be triggered forever at each add call. you should not trig the timer in the add function (which is an interface) but directly in the counter loop:

```
-module(count).
-compile(export_all).

counter(State) ->
  receive
    {add, Number} ->
      NewNumber = State+Number,
      timer:apply_after(1000, ?MODULE, add, [self(), 10]),
      counter(NewNumber);
    resolve ->
          counter(0);
    {From, get} ->
          From ! {self(), State},
          counter(State);
    terminate ->
       ok
   end.

add(Pid, Number) ->
  Pid ! {add, Number}.

resolve(Pid) ->
  Pid ! resolve.

get(Pid) -> 
  Pid ! {self(),get},
  receive
    {P,V} -> 
      io:format("timer ~p value is ~p~n",[P,V]),
      V
  after 3000 ->
    {error,"not responding"}
  end.

stop(Pid) ->
  Pid ! terminate.

start() ->
  Pid = spawn(?MODULE, counter, [0]),
  timer:apply_after(1000, ?MODULE, add, [Pid, 10]),
  Pid.
```

example:

```
1> c(count).
{ok,count}
2> P = count:start().
<0.63.0>
3> {ok,TRef} = timer:apply_interval(2000,count,get,[P]).
{ok,{interval,#Ref<0.0.4.100>}}
4> timer <0.63.0> value is 110
timer <0.63.0> value is 130
timer <0.63.0> value is 150
timer <0.63.0> value is 170
timer <0.63.0> value is 190
timer <0.63.0> value is 210
timer <0.63.0> value is 230
timer <0.63.0> value is 250
count:resolve(P).
resolve
5> timer <0.63.0> value is 10
timer <0.63.0> value is 30
timer <0.63.0> value is 50
timer <0.63.0> value is 70
timer <0.63.0> value is 90
timer <0.63.0> value is 110
timer <0.63.0> value is 130
timer <0.63.0> value is 150
timer <0.63.0> value is 170
count:stop(P).
terminate
6> timer:cancel(TRef).
{ok,cancel}
7>
```